# How to install standard system commands for amazon-linux 2

Tags: docker, amazon-linux

I seem to be missing some very basic utilities, namely the commands `sudo` and `which` seem to be missing. How can I install these, or even better is there an ami linux image which has all of these kind of things pre-installed.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190823.1-with-sources
RUN echo $(which sudo)
```

Error:

`/bin/sh: which: command not found`

Or if I just try to use something like `sudo yum`

`/bin/sh: sudo: command not found`

Since it seems relevant, I also don't seem to have root permissions as trying to use the `adduser` command gives me a non zero response code of 2.

Comment: `RUN yum update && yum install -y sudo`, sudo is not installed in that image by default. you are already root in that images so you do not need sudo yum

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty crazy to me. Didn't realise you just used yum to install these regular commands. I feel a bit silly now. Pop that into an answer and I'll mark it as correct @LinPy

Comment: You pretty much never need `sudo` in Docker.  A container usually runs some single process as a foreground job without user intervention, so you don't usually need an interactive shell in a container, and if you do, you can always `docker exec -u 0` to be root.

Comment: I need sudo for sudo -u, not for root permissions. Also in my case I use a docker container as a cli quite often since it has everything I need for the command line installed. Plenty runs in the background and it's often interactive. I also need sudo because prod uses sudo in some scripts, those same scripts need to work on my local.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RUN yum update && yum install -y sudo`, sudo is not installed in that image by default. you are already root in that images so you do not need `sudo yum`.

the idea from not installing too many packages by default ,is to let the image as small as possible and let the user install just what he needs

Comment: `RUN yum -y update && yum install -y sudo` worked for me.

Comment: Also need `yum install -y which`